# Internet Explorer and IPv6

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, ipv6, internet-explorer

I can't seem to stop the IPv6 address being registered by our server. Does anyone know how?

This is causing slow browsing issues when browsing to spiceworks server using Internet Explorer.

The problem is due to Internet Explorer accessing spiceworks [using an IPv6 address when it should be using a IPv4 address](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/189852-2-of-3-browsers-slow-opening-the-user-portal?page=1#entry-1150843).

I've followed the instructions below on how to stop IPv6 addresses being registered, but that didn't help.

- [How to remove or disable IPv6 in Windows Server 2008 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/179954/)
- [How to disable IP version 6 or its specific components in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the answer by typing the following command "netsh interface 6to4 set state disabled".  Not sure on the ramifications but its solved the immediate problem.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. You shouldn't need 6to4/Teredo for anything these days.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the `AAAA` record from DNS after you turned off IPv6?

If you've disabled it, it certainly won't be registering any more - but if DNS scavenging hasn't gotten rid of the entry, you'll still see issues from it.

Comment: Yeah i removed the AAAA manually. It still gets recreated.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Seems like it's still using IPv6, then.  What's the current status of IPv6 addresses on the adapter?

Comment: From a IP config /all: the only IPv6 address we can see is for the tunnel adaptor: Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:  2002:c022:62f7::c022:62f7(Preferred)

Comment: Is that address the one that's being registered?  I believe those addresses are registered in DNS by default.